# Approximate Simultaneous Diagonalization of Non-Hermitian Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues, eigenvector

Let $A_1,A_2$ two $n\times n$ complex matrices. $A_1$ and $A_2$ are also non-normal, especially, non-hermitian and do not commute. I would like to find an invertible matrix $V$ such that
$$
\sum_{i=1,2} || \textrm{off}( VA_iV^{-1} ) ||_F
$$
is minimal and where $\textrm{off}(.)$ sets the main diagonal to zero. There is a lot of literature on Hermitian $A_i$ and unitary $V$. In the non-Hermitian case, the transform is then $VA_iV^{H}$ instead. However, I cannot find any literature on this specific case. If it is of any help, $A_i$ are non-hermitian, but commuting matrices corrupted by noise.